# Coming Up with a Good Algorithm for a Simple Idea

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js

I need to come up with an algorithm that does the following:

Lets say you have an array of positive numbers (e.g. `[1,3,7,0,0,9]`) and you know beforehand their sum is 20.

You want to abstract some average amount from each number such that the new sum would be less by 7.

To do so, you must follow these **rules**:

- you can only subtract integers
- the resulting array must not have any negative values
- you can not make any changes to the indices of the buckets.

The more uniformly the subtraction is distributed over the array the better.

Here is my attempt at an algorithm in JavaScript + underscore (which will probably make it n^2):

```
function distributeSubtraction(array, goal){
    var sum = _.reduce(arr, function(x, y) { return x + y; }, 0);
    if(goal < sum){
      while(goal < sum && goal > 0){
         var less = ~~(goal / _.filter(arr, _.identity).length); //length of array without 0s
         arr = _.map(arr, function(val){ 
            if(less > 0){
                return (less < val) ? val - less : val; //not ideal, im skipping some! 
            } else {
                if(goal > 0){ //again not ideal. giving preference to start of array
                    if(val > 0) {
                        goal--;
                        return val - 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    return val;
                }
            }
         });
         if(goal > 0){
             var newSum = _.reduce(arr, function(x, y) { return x + y; }, 0);
             goal -= sum - newSum;
             sum = newSum;
         } else {
            return arr;
         }
      }
    } else if(goal == sum) {
      return _.map(arr, function(){ return 0; });
    } else {
      return arr;
    }
}
var goal = 7;
var arr = [1,3,7,0,0,9];
var newArray = distributeSubtraction(arr, goal);
//returned: [0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 7];
```

Well, that works but there must be a better way! I imagine the run time of this thing will be terrible with bigger arrays and bigger numbers.

**edit**: I want to clarify that this question is purely academic. Think of it like an interview question where you whiteboard something and the interviewer asks you how your algorithm would behave on a different type of a dataset.

Comment: what are the practical dimensions of your problem? is the length of your array large? is the sum large? is the difference/goal to apply large? (in other words: define "better" and motivate why)

Comment: When i say better, i mean a faster runtime and or more elegant code. In a case of a large dataset i would care about runtime more than beauty. If the dataset is small - id rather see nice code. (My problem's dataset is small, but this seems like an interesting problem in general)

Comment: Ok, great, better means faster, is the length of your arrays large? Is the change you have to apply large? Which one do you expect to vary as your problem scales? (if I were interviewing a candidate, I'd provide some guidance on the efficiency I'm interested in, which is why I ask. If you're looking for efficiency in N, the length of the array, that's cool, just want to know)

Comment: in my 'exact' problem my arrays should never be bigger than 50 in length and the subtraction goal should never be greater than 20% of the sum. As this problem scales i expect only array length to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to subtract a weighted amount from each number. I.E you want to subtract `X/sum * amount_to_subtract` from each item. You would of course need to round the amount your subtracting. The problem is then making sure that you've subtracted the total correct amount. Also, this depends on your input: are you guaranteeing that that the amount you want to subtract *can* be subtracted? Here's a rough python implementation, (I think):

```
def uniform_array_reduction(inp, amount):
  total = sum(inp)
  if amount > total:
    raise RuntimeError('Can\'t remove more than there is')

  if amount == total: #special case
    return [0] * len(inp)

  removed = 0
  output = []
  for i in inp:
    if removed < amount:
      to_remove = int(round(float(i)/float(total)*float(amount)))
      output.append(i - to_remove)
      removed += to_remove
    else:
      output.append(i)
  # if we didn't remove enough, just remove 1 from
  # each element until we've hit our mark.
  # shouldn't require more than one pass
  while removed < amount:
    for i in range(len(output)):
      if output[i] > 0:
        output[i] -= 1
        removed += 1
        if removed == amount:
          break
  return output
```

EDIT: I've fixed a few bugs in the code.

Comment: i think this algorithm can cause negative numbers in the output array, which is one thing i am not allowed to have

Comment: i dont think i was clear about that rule :P edited my question

Comment: It shouldn't have negative numbers. It only ever removes a fraction of the total amount to remove. The sample inputs I've been running through it all seem to work. If that's really a worry, it's easy enough to say `to_remove = min(to_remove, i)`

Comment: `which is one thing i am not allowed to have` do you mind re-clarifying the purpose for this again?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = Sum(x) - required_sum
do:
    a = ceil( s/number_of_non_zeros(x) )
    For i=1 to length(x):
        v = min(a, x[i], s)
        x[i]-=v
        s-=v
while s>0
```

This version needs no sorting.

Comment: i want the orinal array back with the subtractions. sorting it first modifies the array. sorry, should have included this as a 'rule'

Comment: @mkoryak This version does not need sorting.

Comment: @mkoryak In a earlier version I was explicitly calculating number_of_non_zeros and I forgot to remove those two lines